# 1 or 0 based on values in another column? [python]

Tags: python, indexing, rolling-computation, threshold

I am trying to append a column to a data frame that is based on another column in that data frame, where the values directly correspond to the other column. I am having a lot of trouble trying to articulate this well, so I will just demonstrate. I am working in Python.

I have the following data frame:

```
           DateTime      Value
--------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1
2015-03-11 07:00:00          2
2015-03-11 08:00:00          2
2015-03-11 09:00:00          3
2015-03-11 10:00:00          3
2015-03-11 11:00:00          2
2015-03-11 12:00:00          4
2015-03-11 13:00:00          6
2015-03-11 14:00:00          5
2015-03-11 15:00:00          3
2015-03-11 16:00:00          3
2015-03-11 17:00:00          2
2015-03-11 18:00:00          1
...
```

Now I want to append a column to this data frame that is based on the "Value" column, called "Value_2". I want "Value_2" to display all "1" values, and then find the first instance of 3 or more consecutive values >= 4 (a threshold essentially), display "1" values for the first 2 of those 3 hours, and then produce all "0" values onward, like so:

```
           DateTime      Value       Value_2
---------------------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1             1  
2015-03-11 07:00:00          2             1
2015-03-11 08:00:00          2             1
2015-03-11 09:00:00          3             1
2015-03-11 10:00:00          3             1
2015-03-11 11:00:00          2             1 
2015-03-11 12:00:00          4             1
2015-03-11 13:00:00          6             1
2015-03-11 14:00:00          5             0
2015-03-11 15:00:00          3             0  
2015-03-11 16:00:00          3             0
2015-03-11 17:00:00          2             0  
2015-03-11 18:00:00          1             0  
...
```

This would represent a "tolerance" value of 2 hours, after which any more hours (consecutively) of values >= 4 would results in all 0s onward. I am trying to produce code so that I can easily change this "tolerance" value of 2 hours to 3 hours (meaning that after the first consecutive 3 values >= 4, a single additional consecutive value >= 4 would result in all 0s onward), like so:

```
           DateTime      Value       Value_2
---------------------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1             1  
2015-03-11 07:00:00          2             1
2015-03-11 08:00:00          2             1
2015-03-11 09:00:00          3             1
2015-03-11 10:00:00          3             1
2015-03-11 11:00:00          2             1 
2015-03-11 12:00:00          4             1
2015-03-11 13:00:00          6             1
2015-03-11 14:00:00          5             1
2015-03-11 15:00:00          4             0  
2015-03-11 16:00:00          3             0
2015-03-11 17:00:00          2             0  
2015-03-11 18:00:00          1             0  
...
```

I would like to be able to change this "tolerance" value to any number. And by "tolerance" I just mean how many consecutive rows of values >= 4 in the "Value" column can get translated to 1s in the "Value_2" column before they become all 0s onward.

Can this be done in a simple way in python? So far, I have the following thanks to a very helpful suggestion I received:

```
df['helper'] = np.where(df["Value"] >= 4, 1, 0)
tolerance = 3
df['helper_sum'] = df['helper'].rolling(tolerance, min_periods=1).sum()
first_index = df.loc[df['helper_sum']==tolerance,'helper_sum'].index[0]
df['value_2'] = 0 
df.loc[df.index<=first_index, 'value_2'] = 1
```

This works. However, when I change my threshold of >= 4 to >= 7, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I believe this is because there are no values of >= 7 in my short dataset here, and so the code just doesn't comprehend >= 7, but I am not sure. I would like to fix the code so that it can work for any threshold value, even if that value is not contained within the dataset. For a threshold of >= 7, I would expect to see the `Value_2` column just contain 0s all the way down, since a value of >= 7 is of course never seen. Can this be fixed?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Ah sorry, thank for pointing that out. I just edited the question. It is Python.

Comment: You should tag it as [python]. Then the Python experts on this site are likely to get your question in their feed.